# Capture more than one value from URL with Flask/Python

Tags: python, flask

I want to pass values to my Python script based on what button was clicked in the HTML. I can do it like this if there is only one value:

```
@app.route('/', defaults={'category': ''})
@app.route('/<category>')
def index(category):
```

But altogether there are 3 values what I want to capture, and I can't figure out how to do that. All of these values are optional. One (a sorting method) has a default value set, the other two are not set by default.

How can I make this work within a single function and 3 variables? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `request.args` for query string parameters, which will be optional:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    category = request.args.get('category', '')
    attr1 = request.args.get('attr1')
    attr2 = request.args.get('attr2')
```

`request.args` is a dict (more exactly a MultiDict).

A request would look like this

`/?category=my_category&attr1=some_value&attr2=some_value`
or

`/?attr1=some_value`

`/`

Answer (score 0):

You can set more than 1 variable in your routing/function:

```
@app.route('/', defaults={'category': '', 'var2': '', 'var3': ''})
@app.route('/<category>/<var2>/<var3>')
def index(category, var2, var3):
```